# Android retrofit can't parse all data from header of response

Tags: android, header, retrofit, response, okhttp

When I debugging like image below, headers's size is 10.

[image]

But when I use Postman, the headers's size is 13.

[image: PostMan]
How can I get all key & values from headers?

Comment: Is TeleSense your employer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of Retrofit version 2.3.0.
 It worked well when I use Retrofit version 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Use `response.networkResponse.headers`. That object has headers that have been handled and removed by OkHttp’s built-in interceptors.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response/network-response/